# Is it possible to use SCP or FTP to copy files and then run an install script?

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a set of files to be copied to a lot of remote UNIX/Linux servers.This set of files also has a install.sh script.

Is there a way i can use scp/ftp to copy the files and then run the install.sh ?

Comment: No. Neither scp nor sftp can (by itself) run a script.

Comment: But if you can use `scp`, you probably can also use `ssh`, don't you?  With that you can call the command (`install.sh`) remotely.

Answer (score 4):

If you have scp you likely have ssh. If you have password less ssh login via private keys, you could write a bash script that scps files then calls the script after completed.

Roughly like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
    scp -i /path/to/identity_file "$f" remoteUser@remoteHost:/upload/path/"$f"
done
ssh -i /path/to/identity_file remoteUser@remoteHost bash /upload/path/install.sh
```

Comment: For an answer this is a little too short ;-)  I wrote this as a comment.  For an answer you should elaborate a little more (and at least finish your sentence with a full stop ;-)

Comment: @Alfe, Added a test snippet; and a period. :P

Comment: ⁺¹ from me for your efforts :)